# In Ember.js, how do you make requests to an API that are outside of the REST convention?

Tags: ember.js

I would like to request a 'reset password' endpoint e.g GET -> `user/password/reset` on an API. What is the best way to map this request in ember.js? It doesn't seem appropriate to setup a full ember.js model for this kind of request, as it doesn't have a proper ID and is not really a request for a record, but a triggered event with a success/fail response. Am I incorrectly implementing the REST convention or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple ember-object to represent password reset and then basic ajax. Something like this:

```
App.User.reopenClass({
  resetPassword: function(subreddit) {
    return $.getJSON("user/password/reset").then(
      function(response) {
        console.log('it worked');
        return true;
      },
      function(response) {
        console.log('fail');
        return false;
      }
    );
  }
});
```

See http://eviltrout.com/2013/03/23/ember-without-data.html

That said, this could be a sign that the API endpoint should change. Ideally GET requests should not have side effects, so a GET that resets a password is not recommended. If you think of reset as a `password reset request`, the reset password endpoint that makes the most sense is POST -> user/password/reset to *create* a new request.